# Is it possible to do 'not' matching in XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

Is it possible to create an XPath expression that matches all child nodes that are not of a certain name? E.g.

```
<a>
 <b />
 <c />
 <d />
 <e />
 <f />
 <g />
</a>
```

How would I select all children of the 'a' node that are *not* a 'b' node?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
/a/*[not(self::b)]
```

Comment: Quick and perfect :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Or with XPath 2.0

```
/a/(* except b)
```